# Refactoring issue in Javascript when parsing arguments to MongodB as keys

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two functions which are almost identical except for one of the values to be $set as shown:

```
            function extracted_start(details, txt) {
                return FutureTasks.upsert({
                        number: details.number,
                        start_date: details.start_date,
                        end_date: details.end_date
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            access_rights: txt,
                        }
                    },
                );
            }

            function extracted_end(details, txt) {
                return FutureTasks.upsert({
                        number: details.number,
                        start_date: details.start_date,
                        end_date: details.end_date
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            returned_status: txt,
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
```

If I tried to refactor as below then I get 'key' as not being used?

```
            function extracted_generic(details, key, txt) {
                return FutureTasks.upsert({
                        number: details.number,
                        start_date: details.start_date,
                        end_date: details.end_date
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            key: txt,
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using key as a literal value instead of the variable. You'll have to create an object and add it manually with `obj[key] = txt`. (Side note: you've also spelled 'generic' wrong in your function name.)

```js
function extracted_generaic(details, key, txt) {
  var obj = {},
      obj[key] = txt;

  return FutureTasks.upsert({
    number: details.number,
    start_date: details.start_date,
    end_date: details.end_date,
  }, {
    $set: obj
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `key` is being interpreted is the literal word `"key"` - create your object first and use that:

```
var objToSet = {};
objToSet[key] = txt;
..
..
$set: objToSet
```

Comment: var obj = {},
      obj[key] = txt; 

is this correct syntax?

Comment: Is it:
   var obj = {}, obj[key] = txt; 

or
    var obj = {}; obj[key] = txt;

Comment: I dont see a difference?

Comment: var obj = {}, <- ends with comma or var obj = {}; <- ends with semi colon

Comment: It's the semicolon ending. Just like in the answer. Is something wrong with it?